# How exactly does Weaver's Geminate Attack work?

Tags: dota-2

What is the time between basic attack and geminate attack? Does it depends on attack speed?
Does time between two basic attacks depends on whether geminate attack is done between them?

Also, according to my experience geminate attack have infinite range (ones basic attack is done geminate always follows). Is this correct or there are some limitations?

Comment: It depends on the cooldown, which is reduced per level.

Comment: @Randomizer and how it depends on the cooldown? Proportional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geminate attack is pretty simple to understand yet there are some tricky mechanics that are not obvious at first sight.

### When does Geminate Attack proc

Geminate Attack has a [cooldown (6/5/4/2.5 sec)](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Geminate_Attack#Geminate_Attack) which means the second attack can proc only when Geminate Attack is off cooldown thus :

- You need Geminate Attack to be off cooldown
- You need to hit a target so the second attack can fire
- There can't exist more than 1 Geminate Attack mid-air at once

### Geminate Attack mechanic

- The range is infinite : if the target run away fast enough from your first attack, when it's hit the Geminate Attack will proc and reach the target no matter how far it went.
- If Geminate Attack's cooldown comes to 0 while a normal attack is mid-air, Geminate Attack will proc when this attack hit.  This means you don't have to wait the cooldown to be at 0 to get a Geminate proc but you can shoot a little earlier.
- Since Geminate Attack has a cooldown, it is not impacted by Weaver's attack speed. Increasing Weaver's attack speed will just increase the amount of normal attack you shoot and Geminate Attack will proc every time it's off cooldown.
- Geminate Attack procs are independent of normal attacks. Shooting a Geminate attack will not impact your normal attack rate. Concider Geminate Attack as a bonus shot that will fire between your normal attacks : *If Weaver shoots 2 Attack per second you will hit your target twice per second + a bonus hit every time Geminate Attack is off cooldown.*
- Geminate Attack is fired instantly when the target is hit and if the spell is off cooldown. roughly : *a target is hit by a normal attack > the game checks if Geminate Attack is off cooldown > if yes a bonus shot is fired*.

Comment: I think the geminate attack also cannot be a critical hit, which should be integrated into your 'orb effect' bulletpoint

Comment: @WizLiz, thanks for the range and additional info, but what about timing? My question was: "What is the time between basic attack and geminate attack? 
Does time between two basic attacks depends on whether geminate attack is done between them?"

Comment: @klm123 ok that was unclear, i'll edit my answer

Comment: oh, I see, it depends on when target is hit..

Comment: Yes the spell works like this : a normal attack hit a target > check if Geminate is off CD > if yes : fire a bonus shot.